# Invalid literal for base int10

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

When running a Tkinter Python program, I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
 return self.func(*args)
 File ".\tkintertesting2.py", line 18, in trylogin
if int(Password) == passcode:
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

The code basically takes two inputs from the user and compares them to see if they are valid credentials. Currently, It prints that any value is wrong and gives the error listed above:

```
import tkinter

def trylogin():
    global wxy
    global s
    IDnumberz = s
    Password = wxy
    allowed_Usernames = [13702,1234,2]
    allowed_PassCode = [8702,8535,1212]
    for username in allowed_Usernames:
        if int(IDnumberz) == username:
            correct_username = 1
            print ("good0")
            break
        else:
            correct_username = 0
            print (IDnumberz)
    for passcode in allowed_PassCode:
        if int(Password) == passcode:
            correct_password = 1
            print ("good1")
            break
        else:
            correct_password = 0
            print (Password)
    if correct_password == 1 and correct_username == 1:
        print ("Access granted. Welcome back!")
    else:
        print ("Uh oh! Something with your login was wrong!")

window = tkinter.Tk() #Create Window
window.title("AutoChange v1.3") #Rename window
window.geometry("600x600")
window.wm_iconbitmap('favicon.ico')
photo = tkinter.PhotoImage(file= "logo.gif")
photopacker = tkinter.Label(window, image=photo)
window.configure(background="#a1dbcd")

usernamelabel = tkinter.Label(window, text="Username", bg="#a1dbcd", )
usernamenter = tkinter.Entry(window,)
IDnumber = tkinter.IntVar()
s = IDnumber.get()

passwordlabel = tkinter.Label(window, text="Password", bg="#a1dbcd")
wxy = tkinter.IntVar()
passwordenter = tkinter.Entry(window, textvariable=wxy)
password = tkinter.StringVar()
wxy = password.get()

loginbutton = tkinter.Button(window, text="Login", bg="#a1dbcd",
                             command=trylogin)

#PACK
photopacker.pack()
usernamelabel.pack()
usernamenter.pack()
passwordlabel.pack()
passwordenter.pack()
loginbutton.pack()
window.mainloop() #Start Window
```

Comment: @Erik Johnson, would changing StringVar to IntVar do the trick?

Comment: I had to look closely to see where you were going with this, and I think there may be two issues together affecting you. This got too long for a comment; I'm editing my answer to give more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to disagree with the other answerers who've said that your issue has nothing to do with `tkinter`. It does, a little bit.

The core issue is that you're not reading the user ID and password fields from your GUI when you press the the "Login" button. Rather, you're accessing the `s` and `wxy` variables that hold values that at one time may have belonged to those fields, but probably don't any more by the time you press the button.

Actually `s` reads the initial value from your global variable `IDnumber` (an `IntVar`). That `IDnumber` isn't actually hooked up to anything though, so I suspect it will always be zero. `wxy` is initially an `IntVar` itself, and hooked in the the GUI, but it is later overwritten with a value fetched from from the `password` variable (a `TextVar`). So it's probably always an empty string.

The first thing to fix is reading the values from your `Entry` fields properly.

I suggest the following, though there are probably other ways to do more or less the same thing (e.g. using `TextVar`s, or not using variable wrappers at all and just calling `get` on the `Entry`s themselves, and doing the integer conversion yourself):

```
usernamelabel = tkinter.Label(window, text="Username", bg="#a1dbcd", )
IDnumber = tkinter.IntVar()
usernamenter = tkinter.Entry(window, textvariable=IDnumber)

passwordlabel = tkinter.Label(window, text="Password", bg="#a1dbcd")
password = tkinter.IntVar()
passwordenter = tkinter.Entry(window, textvariable=password)
```

No `get` calls happen at this point! They go in the `trylogin` function:

```
def trylogin():
    id_num = IDnumber.get()
    password_num = password.get()
    # ...
```

You don't need a `global` statement to access global variables (only if you want to assign new values to them).

This will work, assuming your user puts in an integer value in both `Entry` boxes. If they don't however (including if they leave one or both boxes empty), you'll get an exception again, because `IntVar.get` calls `int` on the value it has been `set` to (which will always be a string, internally). So, you probably want to wrap your `get` calls in `try`/`except` blocks and do something when the value is no good. I'm not sure what an appropriate reaction would be in your program, so I'll leave the details up to you. Here's the general structure:

```
def trylogin():
    try:
        id_num = IDnumber.get()
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid user ID") # replace this with some GUI error reporting?
        return

    try:
        password_num = password.get()
    except:
        print("invalid password (must be an integer)")
        return

    # ...
```

I suspect there are other issues with the logic in your code, but I'll stop here, as I think this addresses the exception you're getting in your current code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic Python issue, nothing to do with the Tkinter part.  The value for Password is ""; int("") will raise that error in Python.  You can't take the integer value of a string; the types don't work that way.  You'll need to do a more formal hash/conversion to compare to the passcodes.

---

Edited to reply to Tmanzz122's comment:

This is messier than I'd realized on first look; you have several errors stacked on top of each other.

You have global variables "password" and "wxy", and you also have a variable local to try_login called "Password", whose value is set to wxy.  (My original answer had that as a string value, not a variable - my bad, switching languages too often.) That local variable is the variable you're actually trying to take the int() of when you get your crash.

When I went to actually run your code snippet, I added a print statement and noticed that Password and wxy both had a blank string as their value.  That's the root of your problem - your value isn't getting passed in.  If you look at your crash trace, you'll see it there too.

This is because you can't get the value of `wxy` by a simple assignment - you need to use the getter:

```
Password = wxy.get()
```

When I added that, it still crashed, which confused me.  The crash was

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

which meant that wxy was NOT the StringVar you intended it to be, but was a simple string (which is why it was a blank string when you used it).  The culprit there was the line where you reassigned wxy to be the result of password.get() AFTER setting it as your textvariable.  When I commented that line out, things worked as expected - I failed to login because I was putting garbage into the fields.

Use the getter to get the value of wxy, and don't overwrite it before using it, and you'll be able to move on.  Good luck!

Comment: There's no string `"wxy"` in the code we've been shown. `wxy` is the name of a global variable.

Comment: True.  That was me reading Python as if it were Tcl (long day, head cold, etc.).  I've updated to give a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting the user input to an `int`, you can convert the password you're testing against to a string:

```
if Password == str(passcode):
```

A better solution would be to store strings in the list of passcodes so that no conversion is necessary, and any string (not just numerics) can be used.

The design of your algorithm is a bit suspect too, since *any* combination of valid ID and passcode will get through. Usually you want to associate a specific passcode to a specific ID.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things working against you. There are two simple fixes:

#### Get the value of the input fields when you need them

You are setting `pasword` immediately after creating the widget. The user doesn't have a chance to enter anything before you set the value. Instead, get the value from inside `trylogin`:

```
def trylogin()
    password = passwordenter.get()
    ...
```

Note that this isn't a workaround. This is a very, very common pattern in UI development.

The second thing to notice is that you don't need to use a `StringVar` or `IntVar`. Those add overhead and don't provide you any benefit (at least, not the way you are using them). You can directly access the contents of the widget without the need for the `textvariable` attribute of the widget. You can use one if you want, but in this case it's just extra overhead.

#### Be prepared for user input that isn't a valid number

The error message you report is from trying to convert the password to an integer, and the password was an empty string at the time of the conversion. You will get similar errors if the value has anything other than digits (ie: if the user types "5uper5ecretP@ssw0rd!")

The simplest solution is to use strings for allowed passwords. If you do that, checking the password is one line of code:

```
allowed_PassCode = ['8702', '8535', '1212']
password = passwordenter.get()

# the one-line check:
if password in allowed_PassCode:
    print ("good0")
```

If you prefer for the allowed passcodes to actually be integers, that's fine. You just need to put your conversion in a try/catch block. With this, if the user enters something that's not a number, password will be set to `None`, and `None` isn't in the list of valid passwords, so the user is locked out.

```
allowed_PassCode = [8702, 8535, 1212]
try:
    password = int(passwordenter.get())
catch ValueError:
    password = None

if password in allowd_PassCode:
    ...
```